# Use TFS with WebStorm and Visual Studio on same machine

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, webstorm

I am working on a project which includes a .NET backend with some heavy JavaScript front end code.

We use TFS for source control.

For working in JavaScript I want to use WebStorm, which has a TFS plugin.

For working in .NET I want to work in Visual Studio which supports TFS.

Ideally, I would like both IDEs to point to the same local code, and both be able to check in changes that I make to that code. I would only have one IDE open at any point in time, depending on whether I am working on the JavaScript or the .NET side of the code.

I've tried pointing both IDEs at the same local folder, and having them both work from different local folders connected to the same TFS workspace. But WebStorm never seems to recognise that I've changed a file, or that a file checked into TFS is different to the local one.

It could just be that the TFS plug in for Webstorm is flaky. But it might be that I am approaching it wrong.

Has anyone ever tried this?  And if so, how did you get it working?

Comment: what TFS workspace do you use - server or local? The latter is not supported

Comment: It's a server workspace Lena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking on the Root folder and select "TFS\Checkin Directory..." option from WebStorm to see if the changes can be detected. I just tried it and it can detect the changes made in VS.

However, Use the same work space in multiple instance is not supported officially.

> Q: Can I use the same workspace in multiple instances of Visual
> Studio?
>
> A: Although Visual Studio does not block you from running
> multiple instances against the same workspace, this usage is not
> supported. Also, working this way is more likely to cause problems if
> you are using a local workspace.

Comment: Thanks Eddie. Looks like running multiple instances against same workspace is a bad idea anyway, and the WebStorm TFS plug in seems very buggy. So I'm using Webstorm to edit JavaScript, but VisualStudio for all checking in and out. Works fine, without too much hassle, other than having both open at once. I'd love to know how others do it.